# No way to execute SQL script from SQL Server Query Manager like @{file.sql} oracle sqlplus syntax?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sqlplus

Like the title says, in oracle you can issue the following command in SQL*Plus:

```
SQL> select something from anothertable; #sql
SQL> @{/home/me/somescript.sql};         #load sql from file and execute it
SQL> do something else in script;        #other sql
```

Without having to file->open the sql script to load it to the UI.

Is there an equivalent in SQL Server Query Manager? I've stumbled upon many situation where i could have used it but i couldn't be able to find a way to accomplish it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If using latter versions of SQL Server (2005 & 2008), see if the `:r` command in SQLCMD works for you:

*:r <filename>
Parses additional Transact-SQL statements and sqlcmd commands from the file specified by <filename> into the statement cache.
If the file contains Transact-SQL statements that arenot followed by GO, you must enter GO on the line that follows :r.*
From [sqlcmd Utility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Thank you Shannon, it's a pity that it is not possible to use that command in the Query Analyzer / Management Studio. But when combining the SQLCMDs -i switch with a script containing :r commands, that would be what i was looking for.

Comment: edit: Ok, it is possible to include and execute a script directly from within the SQLcmd shell, but you cannot build scripts that reference other scripts, the oracle way. When including a :r in a sql script file and load that file into SQLCMD it does not recognize the :r commands and fails executing.

Answer (score 5):

You're not really comparing like for like Tools here.

The equivalent tool to SQL*Plus in SQL Server is the [SQLCMD Utility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx).

In particular you will be interested in the **-i** switch as this allows you to provide a .sql file as input.

***Edit:***

In response to your comment, you could look to use the system stored procedure [xp_cmdshell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175046.aspx) to launch a prompt form within a T-SQL batch that allows you to use SQLCMD. Not the most elegant solution in my opinion but it should work.

Comment: Thanks for your hint.what i want to achieve is referencing a script from another script. Scenario is a migration and i have to reference several scripts from sql, whether it is SQL Management Studio or isql, doesn't matter. But i dont know if there's a way to accomplish it the SQL*Plus way.

Comment: With the -i switch i would have to switch focus from ISQL back to CMD and issue another ISQL -i file.sql command.

Comment: xp_cmdshell will launch the shell relative to the server, not relative to where ovm is nescessarily running the batch.

Answer (score 1):

Use isql utility http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa214007(SQL.80).aspx

issql ... -iinputfile

Comment: Thank you, too. please see above comments.

Answer (score 1):

There is also SQLS*Plus tool that you can use to execute scripts within a script